# Gradient layer is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gradient

I have the code for making gradient but it's simply not showing. If I change the color of view that holds that gradient, I can see it. So the view is fine, just gradient has some issues. This is my code:

```
class KolodaCardView: UIView {
    var helloWorld = "Hello World"
    var userImage = UIImageView()
    var userName = UILabel()
    var parent = UIView()
    var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    var gradientView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        parent = self
        parent.backgroundColor = .clear
        parent.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        parent.clipsToBounds = true

        setupUserImage()
        setupUserName()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = gradientView.frame
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupUserImage() {
        parent.addSubview(userImage)
        userImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(parent)
            make.bottom.equalTo(parent)
            make.left.equalTo(parent)
            make.right.equalTo(parent)
        }
        userImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        userImage.clipsToBounds = true
        userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 16

        userImage.addSubview(gradientView)
        gradientView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
            make.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(60)
        }
//        gradientView.backgroundColor = .green
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.locations = [0.5,1.0]
        gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }

    func setupUserName() {
        parent.addSubview(userName)
        userName.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(parent).offset(16)
            make.right.equalTo(parent)
            make.height.equalTo(20)
            make.bottom.equalTo(-20)
        }
        userName.textColor = .black
        userName.textAlignment = .left
    }
}
```

I checked several solutions here but nothing works! Can somebody check if maybe I am overlooking something?

[image]

Comment: "If I change the color of view that holds that gradient" How? Could it be that the index used `insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)` is wrong?

Comment: userImage.addSubview(gradientView) add this view at last when you perform your gradient color task

Comment: where you call that method ???

Comment: I added my code to `layoutSubviews()` but still nothing changes.

Comment: @Kira please update your question with your latest code

Comment: Question updated!

Comment: @Kira Check my code

Comment: Did you found the solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: I used some workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

In Gradient you have to give location of your gradient color that fill your layer with their start point to end point.

```
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
gradientLayer.colors =  [UIColor.red.cgColor ,UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.5,1.0]
your_gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: Even if your code snippet solves the issue, you should mention an explanation of what the snippet does...

Comment: I already tried with location and it didn't work. I tried it again and still doesn't wanna show anything.

Comment: @Kira i just update your question just replace your file with this one and run app and show output

Comment: it's doesn't work. I will post an image of my layers in a sec.

Comment: @Kira did you tell us what kind of gradient layer you want to create so we give you best solution for your  question

Comment: Simple linear gradient.